# find mmin X min - is it X min when starting "find" or when "find" find the file?

Tags: find

Assume, I have about 10,000 files in a folder. I have been using hourly crontab to find files that are modified in the last 60 min then process it.

Invoke `find -mmin -60` at 01:00:00

Assume 1st file was modified at 00:00:00 and easily found by "find" at 01:00:00.

Then, assume the 10,000th file was modified at 00:00:00 as well

but **now is at 01:10:00** and "find" is still working hard to reach the 10,000th file

So now, at 70min later, will "find" return the 10,000th file that was modified at 00:00:00?

Answer (score 3):

In GNU `find`, the reference time which is used to evaluate files with `-mmin` etc. is [calculated and stored when the expression is parsed](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c#n1414), so in effect when `find` starts.

This means that all such time comparisons use the same time reference for all evaluated files, the time at which `find` parsed its command line.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU find, this is easily tested:

```
% mkdir foo; cd foo; touch a b
% find -mmin 1
.
./a
./b
% find -mmin 1 -exec sleep 120 \; -print 
.     # 2 minutes wait before this showed up
./a   # another 2 minutes before this showed up
./b   # and another 2 minutes for this one
% find -mmin 1
%
```

So even though `b` was last modified at least 4 minutes after `find` ran `sleep 120` for `a`, it still matched.

---

Since `-mmin` isn't POSIX, this is up to the implementation, but I'd expect the behaviour seen above.

Comment: FWIW, the (FreeBSD-based?) `find` on my Mac also shows both files with `find . -mmin 1 -exec sleep 120 \; -print`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command one after another in two terminals

Terminal 1:

```
find /path -mmin -0.017 -printf "$(date) %Tc %p\n" | grep '/path/to/some/file'
```

Terminal 2:

```
touch -d " 0 seconds ago" /path/to/some/file
```

we are able to get the result as

```
Wed Jul 17 11:48:33 IST 2019 Wed 17 Jul 2019 11:48:34 AM IST /path/to/some/file
```

I'm prefixing the start time of command with find result. it shows, `find` is able to search for the files which are modified after the start time of the command.